# Trying to implement Fittext.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jQuery on my big H1 tag so that the text in the H1 tag will stay the same when resizing my browser window.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/text.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="main">
    <section class="page" id="page1">
        <div class="test">
            <h1>exampletext</h1>
```

CSS:

```
.test h1 {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:250px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:5px;
}
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("test h1").fitText(1, { minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '250px' });
});

(function( $ ){

  $.fn.fitText = function( kompressor, options ) {

    // Setup options
    var compressor = kompressor || 1,
        settings = $.extend({
          'minFontSize' : Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
          'maxFontSize' : Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
        }, options);

    return this.each(function(){

      // Store the object
      var $this = $(this);

      // Resizer() resizes items based on the object width divided by the compressor * 10
      var resizer = function () {
        $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width() / (compressor*10), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
      };

      // Call once to set.
      resizer();

      // Call on resize. Opera debounces their resize by default.
      $(window).on('resize.fittext orientationchange.fittext', resizer);

    });

  };

})( jQuery );
```

It does not seem to work when I resize my browser window, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger like Chrome's Developer toolbar? Is the resize event being triggered? Any output to console?

Comment: @Celice I ran your code and resize event does not trigger.

Comment: Is there anything I could change so that it will work? I only use jQuery to accomplish this so I have no experience with it, only with HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
$("test h1").fitText(1, { minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '250px' });
```

should be

```
$(".test h1").fitText(1, { minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '250px' });
```

you were missing a the fullstop in the query selector

https://jsfiddle.net/craigiswayne/cp5at05y/

Comment: I saw the example in a SASS css, they didn't use selectors so this makes so much sense, thank you!